# How do I create a dynamic range using calculated cell references?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm struggling since I'm not the best with working out the most efficient way to do these things.

Check the following:

"First row with data: 10".
Calculated by a formula that looks for the first data in a column.

"Last row with data: 1128".
Calculated by a formula that looks for the last row with data - the value calculated above.

"Data range **AH10:AH1128**
Calculated by a formula that creates the result from using the previous two result cells.

This then needs to feed into two further calculations:

```
C: = EXP(INDEX(LINEST(**AH10:AH1128**,AO10:AO1128,,),1,2))

B: = INDEX(LINEST(**AH10:AH1128**,AO10:AO1128,,),1)
```

At present I have to change the above formulas manually every time the data changes!

The data is based on a Pivot that updates monthly and the range with expand dynamically. The bottom two formulas calculate the power trend-line C: and B: values which then feed a ready-reckoner calculation in another linked sheet.

I have multiple sheets doing the same job but for filtered results as I cannot see any way to make the formulas work all from one dataset.

It is particularly the first problem though that I need to solve.

Can anyone suggest an idea to fix the issue?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVGPP.png)

Hi Raj - I find that the formulae that you suggested goes doolally when you have blank cells and cells with formulas in that return #N/A, etc results in the list of cells to be counted. How do you adjust to remedy?  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please have a look at the [tour](https://superuser.com/review), you can also attach screenshots.

Comment: @Ross Bames,, better you create a **dynamic defined named Range**, using such formula **=OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNTA($A$2:$A$200),1)** and use the Named Range in Formula.

Comment: **Cont...** or you may use this one too, **=$A$2:INDEX($1:$100,COUNTA($A:$A),COUNTA($1:$1))**

Comment: Hi Raj - sorry for my ignorance but tried these and not worked.  What I think you are suggesting trying to do is create dynamic defined named ranges from data held in a column of data. This needs to exclude some blank cells at the top and bottom and also exclude the data title in AH9. when I try and use your suggestions and adapt for my spreadsheet neither seem to work?

Comment: Show us the formulas you use to get Row 10 and Row 1128, these can be combined to make a dynamic NAMED range for you

Comment: Hi Peter - thanks - the formulae are shown in AP3 and AP4

Comment: Hi Raj - I find that the formulae that you suggested goes doolally when you have blank cells and cells with formulas in that return #N/A, etc results in the list of cells to be counted. How do you adjust to remedy?  Thanks

Comment: @RossBarnes can you include them in your post so I can copy and paste them straight into my excel, and I can put these into an offset to create your dynamic range.

Comment: If your version of Excel supports `Tables`, use that for your data and use [structured references for your ranges](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

Comment: In the end I manage to create named ranges  and used the following which works well, if a bit clunky - thanks for everyone's herp:=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$AO$10:",SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN($AO$3009),4),1,""),VALUE(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($AO$10:$AO$3009="",0),0)*MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($AO$10:$AO$3009>0,0),0)